# App com video chamadas

Tags: android, vídeo, streaming

Eu estou desenvolvendo um app que na teoria deve possibilitar aos usuários o recurso de vídeo chamada, como se tem no `skype`.

Eu me deparei com umas questões.. 
O que seria necessário para colocar um serviço desses em um app Android?
Isso depende de uma streaming como um site?